# Laravel Won't Persist Post in Controller using EmberJs

Tags: php, laravel, ember.js, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with one of my controllers either in Laravel or Ember. I can get the record to save after filling out the form but the record will not persist to the database. Again the form saves the record but doesn't push the record to the database. I tried following Embers guides on pushing data to the server but no juice. Also thanks for all the help from this site, you have got me this far, hopefully I can get this worked out with your help. Here are the controllers,

**Laravel Controller**

```
    $statusCode = 200;
    $libraries = $request->all();
    $library = Library::create($libraries);
    $criteria = $library->toArray();
    return Response::json([
        'libraries' => $criteria],
         $statusCode);
```

**Ember Route**

```
model() {
  return this.store.createRecord('library');
},

actions: {
  saveLibrary(item) {
    item.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('libraries'));
  },

  willTransition() {
    //rollbackAttributes() removes the record from the store
    // if model is 'isNew'

    this.controller.set('model').rollbackAttributes();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your ember controller and not your route? also notice that `willTransition` is not an action.

Comment: Hey Lux good call, this is definitely an Ember route. I thought willTransition was a built-in action?

Comment: its an hook, not an action. So don't put it under the `actions` hash.

Comment: Got it, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, you should use `transitionToRoute`. and implement POST request for `/libraries` for save method call.

```
actions: {
    saveLibrary() {
        //You dont need to pass. you need to update model properties. and then call save method.
        this.get('model').save().then(() => this.transitionToRoute('libraries'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I used transitionToRoute and also the other changes, but still not persisting. I tried taking out the willTransition() action as well and still nothing. Hmm....

Comment: does calling `save()` is requesting network request `/libraries` ?

Comment: Hey kumkanillam, thank you for your continued help. The console says that /libraries request is 200. Do you think it is how ember is pluralizing the model name....ex) my api hook is "libraries" yet my model name in Ember is "library". Idk, I was thinking that I may need to create a new adapter for library because of this but I can't find any specific info on how Ember pluralizes a word like library.

Comment: You don't need to create separate adapter. for saving you should implement POST method `/libraries` thats enough...for more info ..https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_url-conventions

Comment: you are right I did some research on the Inflector-JS library which Ember uses and it looks like it's more than capable of pluralizing the way I need it to. To make sure I am going to test this code with another name but I think your right on not needing to create a separate adapter for the model.